# how to deal with high cardinal categorical feature into numeric for predictive machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have two columns of having high cardinal categorical values, one column(area_id) has 21878 unique values and other has(page_entry) 800 unique values. I am building a predictive ML model to predict the hits on a webpage.

column information:
area_id: all the locations that were visited during the session. (has location code number of different areas of a webpage)

page_entry: describes the landing page of the session.

how to change these two columns into numerical apart from one_hot encoding?

thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can look at [this article on categorical encodings](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-deeper-into-categorical-encodings-for-machine-learning-2312acd347c8), I haven't used by myself most of the techniques presented but it can give you ideas to dig deeper :)

Comment: Hi, @kaggal, if you think the below answer was appropriate, I kindly request you to accept it as a verified answer, since it helps other users who might look into this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to group your categorical levels into smaller buckets using business rules. In your case for the feature `area_id` you could simply group them based on their geographical location, say all `area_ids` from a single district (or for that matter any other level of aggregation) will be replaced by a single `id`. Similarly, for `page_entry` you could group similar pages based on some attributes like nature of the web page like sports, travel, etc.  In this way you could significantly reduce the number dimensions of your variables.